# make at lease one argument mandatory in flask restx reqparser

Tags: python, flask-restx

```
from flask_restx import reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
parser.add_argument('foo', type=int)
parser.add_argument('bar', type=int)
```

I am implementing search endpoint where user can specify /item?foo=f or /item?bar=b to serach items.

I tried raising exception but this just breaks the entire app. What is the correct exception need to raise to display bundled error to end user?

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.foo or not args.bar:
    raise Exception ("Specify Foo or Bar in query string to search item")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, what you need is to raise a werkzeug HTTPException with the correct status code. Flask abort helper can help you with that

Something along this lines

```py
from flask import abort
abort(400, 'some error message')
```